# How to export a fasttext model created by gensim, to a binary file?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, fasttext

I'm trying to export the fasttext model created by gensim to a binary file. But the docs are unclear about how to achieve this. 
What I've done so far:

```
model.wv.save_word2vec_format('model.bin')
```

But this does not seems like the best solution. Since later when I want to load the model using the :

```
fasttext.load_facebook_model('model.bin')
```

I get into an infinite loop. While loading the `fasttext.model` created by `model.save('fasttext.model)` function gets completed in around 30 seconds.

Comment: read this: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#module-gensim.models.fasttext

did you try model.save?

Comment: @Anakin87 You cannot save the model as a `.bin` file using the `model.save` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `.save_word2vec_format()` saves just the full-word vectors, to a simple format that was used by Google's original `word2vec.c` release. It doesn't save unique things about a full FastText model. Such files would be reloaded with the matched `.load_word2vec_format()`.

The `.load_facebook_format()` method loads files in the format saved by Facebook's original (non-Python) FastText code release. (The name of this method is pretty misguided, since 'facebook' could mean so many different things other than a specific data format.) Gensim doesn't have a matched method for saving to this same format – though it probably wouldn't be very hard to implement, and would make symmetric sense to support this export option.

Gensim's models typically implement gensim-native  `.save()` and `.load()` options, which make use of a mix of Python 'pickle' serialization and raw large-array files. These are your best options if you want to save the full model state, for later reloading back into Gensim.

(Such files can't be loaded by other FastText implementations.)

Be sure to keep the multiple related files written by this `.save()` (all with the same user-supplied prefix) together when moving the saved model to a new location.

**Update (May 2020):** Recent versions of `gensim` such as 3.8.3 and later include a new contributed `FastText.save_facebook_model()` method which saves to the original Facebook FastTExt binary format.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. So what should I do if I wanted to make my model file as lightweight as possible and get rid of trainable weights?

Comment: There's not yet a built-in option supporting that (though if there was a matching `.save_facebook_format()` it would fit the bill). You could try nulling-out some of the full model's no-longer-needed properties before doing a `.save()`, though there'd be some risk that results in a model that doesn't do some things it still should, or errors on re-load (so experiment carefully). Discarding the `model.trainables.syn1neg` might work & offer the biggest savings – unsure if other parts of `trainables` could be discarded.

Comment: can't we save the model as a pickle file & load it whenever needed?

Comment: Pickle will break for models over a few GB in size - which are quite common. And the separate arrays saved by `.save()` will load more quickly/efficiently, and give the option of read-only memory-mapped loading – which can offer memory savings in some multi-process deployment scenarios. But you could try it for small models! Also: note my update at the bottom of the answer: recently `gensim` added a `FastText.save_facebook_model()` option.

Comment: I am trying to use the save_facebook_model but I get an error. I cannot find the documentation in gensims web page. Do you know where to find it?

Comment: It appears the online docs at https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html haven't yet been regenerated to show this new option. Until they are, you can read about it directly from the source code, at: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/f767e1e6b719a7688a28d2be356b22d877334339/gensim/models/fasttext.py#L1292